# relative db structure with base data rows over two or more tables

Tags: sql-server, tree, data-modeling

I don‘t know what to Google, so I hope someone can help me here.

Scenario:
I have base data in following tables

```
Element [Id, Name, Description,…]
PartialElement [Id, Name, Description, Position,…]
Parameter [Id, Name, Value,…]
```

An Element can have multiple PartialElements, PartialElements can be referenced by multiple Elements.
A PartialElement can have multiple Parameters, Parameters belong to one PartialElement.

So if I create a new Element, I can add the reference to a PartialElement AND change only the value of the Parameters only in the scope of that Element, if want to, otherwise it will leave the base value I have defined when creating the PartialElement solo.
Any new Element referencing the same PartialElement will also have the default Parameter values, not the one changed before.

If that PartialElement gets a new Parameter, the Element using the PartialElement will be able to change that Parameter in the Element Scope only.

How would I solve that problem in sql?

Is there a concept for ‘movement data’ of base data? Should I copy all PartialElements including their Parameters and add a reference to the base PartialElement checking their Parameters on each call? There must be a nicer pattern or way to do so…

I thought about adding an intermediate table, but having three PK FK felt wrong.

I thought about copying all layers, but that causes a lot of duplicate data

Comment: If i follow you correctly, you can create a PartialElementParameterOverride table where you keep the "changed" parameter values for each Element. To get correct value, you do a LEFT JOIN and ISNULL(partialOverride.value, partial.value). This way specific element changes don't affect the base, and you don't have so many copies. That's how i do this stuff. But it gets more complicated if you also want to add specific parameters not existing in base OR delete them etc. SQL is not really good at these kind of hierarchys. I guess it depends on how often will you have customized Partials vs regular.

Comment: In other systems i used, we always copied from template to the actual "concrete" values, it had some upsides but also some downsides, especially if  you wanted to apply same change to all already created elements

Comment: So u say a document database is the way to go here? It s just that there are traditional fk references and I wouldn’t want to lose all pros of ef, transactions,…

Comment: Nah, i wouldn't go that far. Document database, then you gotta copy everything. That's the worst :D